# IBM DOORS Copy text from column

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm new to DOORS and DXL scripting (not sure if it'll be needed here or not). What I'm looking to do is create a new column in two separate modules that will copy the Absolute Numbers. I know this sounds simple enough, but what I'm running into an issue with is that I use a tool to convert my modules into a PDF and it combines them into one module before doing so. Doing this messes up the Absolute Numbers and I can't afford to have that happen.

More descriptive:
I have a column that contains the following:
'REQ01: 4' where 'REQ01:' represents the module and '4' represents the Absolute Number. Similarly, I have 'REQ02: 4'. I need to copy those in their respective modules and make sure they don't change after the modules have been combined.

I've tried my hand at some DXL scripting and this is what I came up with:

```
displayRich("REQ01: " obj."Absolute Number" "")
```

This appropriately shows the column, but again will not work as the Absolute Number ends up changing when I merge the modules.

Thanks in advanced for your help and I apologize if I left any crucial information out.

Comment: I am not sure what you are using for a utility to combine them so its hard to say what will fix your problem. I would try using a dxl attribute instead. Basically the same thing as the column but it should preserve the value. Let me know if you need help with the DXL portion of the Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that ultimately worked for me.

```
// DXL generated on 11 June 2014 by Attribute DXL wizard, Version 1.0

// The wizard will use the following comments on subsequent runs
// to determine the selected options and attributes. It will not
// take account of any manual changes in the body of the DXL code.

// begin parameters (do not edit)
// One attribute/property per line: true
// Show attribute/property names: false
// Include OLE objects in text: true
// Attribute: Object Text
// end parameters (do not edit)

Module m
AttrDef ad
AttrType at
m = module obj
ad = find(m,attrDXLName)
if(!null ad && ad.object)
{
    at = ad.type
    if(at.type == attrText)
    {
        string s
        Buffer val = create
        Buffer temp = create
        ad = find(m,"Object Text")
        if(!null ad)
        {
            probeRichAttr_(obj,"Object Identifier", temp, true)
            val += tempStringOf temp
        }
        obj.attrDXLName =  richText (tempStringOf val) 
        delete val
        delete temp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a builtin  "Copy Attributes" script which does this. At least in the version installed at my company, it's in the PSToolbox, and also available in the menu *PSToolbox/attributes/copy.../betweenattributes...*  Here you go:

```
// Copy values from one attribute to another

/*
*/

/*
PSToolbox Tools for customizing DOORS with DXL V7.1
-------------------------------------------------
DISCLAIMER:

This programming tool has been thoroughly checked 
and tested at all stages of its production. 
Telelogic cannot accept any responsibility for 
any loss, disruption or damage to your data or 
your computer system that may occur while using 
this script. 

If you do not accept these conditions, do not use 
this customised script.
-------------------------------------------------
*/

if ( !confirm "This script copies values from one attribute to another in the same module.\n" //-
              "Use this to assist in changing the types of attributes.\n\n" //-
              "It asks you to select the source and destination attributes.\n\n" //-
              "It works by ... well, copying attribute values!\n\n" //-
              "Continue?"
   )
{
    halt
} 

#include <addins/PSToolbox/utensils/dbs.inc>

const int MAXATTRS = 1000


DB  copyAttrValsDB      = null
DBE copyAttrValsFrom    = null
DBE copyAttrValsTo      = null
DBE copyAttrValsConfirm = null
DBE copyAttrValsButt    = null

string attrListFrom[MAXATTRS]
string attrListTo[MAXATTRS]

string confirmOpts[] = { "Yes", "Yes to all", "No", "No to all", "Cancel" }

bool confirmDataLoss = true
bool noToDataLoss    = false


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Call-backs

void doAttrValsCopy(DB db) {

    // check attributes
    string fromAn = attrListFrom[get copyAttrValsFrom]
    string toAn   = attrListTo  [get copyAttrValsTo  ]
    if ( fromAn == toAn ) {
        ack "Cannot copy attribute to itself."
        return
    }

    // get confirmation
    if ( !confirm "Confirm copy of attribute '" fromAn "' to attribute '" toAn "'." ) {
        return
    }


    confirmDataLoss = get copyAttrValsConfirm

    // do copy
    Object o
    for o in current Module do 
    {
        Buffer oldVal = create()
        Buffer newVal = create()

        if      ( fromAn == "Object Identifier" ) newVal = identifier(o)
        else if ( fromAn == "Object Level"      ) newVal = level(o) ""
        else if ( fromAn == "Object Number"     ) newVal = number(o)
        else                                      newVal = richText o.fromAn

        oldVal = richText o.toAn

        if ( confirmDataLoss && !noToDataLoss && length(oldVal) > 0 && oldVal != newVal ) 
        {
            current = o
            refresh current
            int opt = query("About to lose attribute '" toAn "' = '" stringOf(oldVal) "' on current object.", confirmOpts)
            if ( opt == 1 ) confirmDataLoss = false
            if ( opt == 2 ) continue
            if ( opt == 3 ) noToDataLoss = true            
            if ( opt == 4 ) return            
        }

        if ( !confirmDataLoss || !noToDataLoss || length(oldVal) == 0 ) o.toAn = richText stringOf(newVal)

        delete(oldVal)
        delete(newVal)
    }

    hide copyAttrValsDB
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Main program

int numAttrsFrom = 0
int numAttrsTo   = 0

AttrDef ad
for ad in current Module do {
    if ( ad.module ) continue
    string an = ad.name
    if ( canRead (current Module, an) ) attrListFrom[numAttrsFrom++] = an
    if ( canWrite(current Module, an) ) attrListTo  [numAttrsTo++  ] = an
}

attrListFrom[numAttrsFrom++] = "Object Identifier"
attrListFrom[numAttrsFrom++] = "Object Level"
attrListFrom[numAttrsFrom++] = "Object Number"


copyAttrValsDB      = create "Copy attribute values"
copyAttrValsFrom    = choice(copyAttrValsDB, "From:", attrListFrom, numAttrsFrom, 0)
copyAttrValsTo      = choice(copyAttrValsDB, "To:",   attrListTo,   numAttrsTo,   0)
copyAttrValsButt    = apply (copyAttrValsDB, "Copy", doAttrValsCopy)
copyAttrValsConfirm = toggle(copyAttrValsDB, "Confirm on loss of data", true)

show copyAttrValsDB
```